# With Bluemix Dedicated, are the registry and File Share hosted outside the private network?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Looking at [Bluemix Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/api/content/containers/images/container_planning_container_ov_bluemixify.png), Docker registry(private and IBM) and file share are shown outside the private network. Is this outdated or not applicable to dedicated?

Comment: The picture shows the file share outside the container private network, but inside the Bluemix private network. See the Bluemix Network Gateway on the right. Is your question related to container private network  or Bluemix private network?

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. My bad. I took the container network for the VPC boundary.

Comment: I will add it as answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [picture referenced by you](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/api/content/containers/images/container_planning_container_ov_bluemixify.png) shows the file share outside the **container private network**, but inside the **Bluemix private network**. So all the components are secure and hidden from the outside world.